# Using labbook.cls, how do I refer to previous experiments/labdays?

Tags: cross-referencing

I'm using `labbook.cls` and properly using `\labday{}` and `\experiment` and `\subexperiment`. I'd like to refer to previous lab days, experiments, or sub experiments.  I know I could label each with `\label`, but I was looking for something more elegant.

Comment: `\labday`  uses `\refstepcounter` to set up `\label` referencing, and `\experiment` is a standard latex section head which therefore does the same. why is it inelegant to use `\label`?

Comment: Are you wanting someway to say "Day 39" when you're in Day 40, without having to use labels and refs?  Otherwise, I'm not sure what you're asking.